# ASP.NET MVC - Where to throw the exceptions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

Best practice to throw the exception if no entry found in the db?

```
// CONTROLLER
public ActionResult Edit(int categoryId, int id)
{
    Product target = Products.GetById(id);
    if (target == null) throw new HttpException(404, "Product not found");

    return View("Edit", target);
}

// REPOSITORY
public Product GetById(int id)
{
    return context.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.productId == id);
}
```

or

```
// CONTROLLER
public ActionResult Edit(int categoryId, int id)
{
    return View("Edit", Products.GetById(id));
}

// REPOSITORY
public Product GetById(int id)
{
    Product target = context.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.productId == id);
    if (target == null) throw new HttpException(404, "Product not found with given id");

    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Never throw an `HttpException` from a repository...it's the wrong level of abstraction. If you don't want your repository to return `null`, do something like this:

```
// CONTROLLER
public ActionResult Edit(int categoryId, int id)
{
    try {
       Product target = Products.GetById(id);
    }
    catch(ProductRepositoryException e) {
       throw new HttpException(404, "Product not found")
    }

    return View("Edit", target);
}

// REPOSITORY
public Product GetById(int id)
{
    Product target = context.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.productId == id);
    if (target == null) throw new ProductRepositoryException();

    return target;
}
```

Your repository should not know anything about HTTP, but your controller can know about the repository. So you throw a repository exception from the repository, and "translate" that into an HTTP Exception in the controller.

Comment: But then I have to create custom exceptions :(?

Comment: Yes you do. And that's what you *should* do.

Comment: I'll just create a custom exception named "NotFoundException" then. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: How do you create this custom exception?

Comment: @niico `throw new Exception()`, at a very basic level. If you want a different type of exception, like `NotFoundException`, then it is `throw new NotFoundException("custom Exception message")` and in your `catch {}` statement where you want to use it, you have `catch(NotFoundException ex)` instead of `catch(Exception ex)`.

Answer (score 3):

Do not throw a HttpException in the Repository, as you may want to reuse that code in the future in a non-Http environment.  Throw your own ItemNotFound exception if you require at least one item and handle that exception in the Controller, or return null and handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I would throw `HttpException` in the controller, and return `null` from the repository.

Comment: Return null from the repository.. that dosent make sense - could you go a bit more in depth please?